# Frame to Timecode Conversion HTML5

Tags: java, video

I'm looking to convert a frame number (for a given sample rate) into time in HTML5.

```
eg:
sample_rate = 24fps
frame 226 => ? time
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

24 fps = 1 second (your sample rate = 1 second)

226 frames / 24 fps = 9,41 seconds

total / frame_rate = time in seconds

Example:

```
video.currentTime = 9.41;
```

Comment: i was using the same logic: time_miliseconds = frame / sample_rate * 1000, but apparently when checking the conversion with this calculator http://www.michaelcinquin.com/tools/timecode_keykode there is a different result for the data above, 226 frames = 9,10

Comment: Sorry, now I know what's wrong. Timecode is calculated time + frames for not integer part. Result is 9,41 (9 seconds and 0.41 from another second. You'll need to find how many frame 0.41 second equals to. 10, in your case.) But I guess HTMl5 doesn't convert float part to frames back... it assumes as double value.